# Inverse of cumulative density function for Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: r, python, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function, multivariate-normal-distribution

How do I calculate the inverse of the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a **multivariate** normal distribution? Does it even exist for the multivariate case?

I know this is possible for a univariate case in python as

```
from scipy.stats import norm    
norm.ppf(0.95, loc=10, scale=2) # mean=10,variance=2, probability=0.95

Out[34]: 0.94999999999999996  # x value corresponding to given probability
```

Can somebody tell me a function similar to this for a **multivariate case in Python or R**?

Sample Input    : mean is a dimensional vector
variance is p*p matrix
probability(between 0 &1)
Expected output : 'x' which would be a p dimensional vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*It doesn't exist.* Consider the most simple case, $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. Gaussians. Because of independence, by definition $f_{XY}(X,Y) = f_X(X)\,f_Y(Y)$. If they are i.i.d., then

$$
f_{XY}(z, -z) = f_{XY}(-z, z) = f_X(-z) \, f_Y(z) = f_X(z) \, f_Y(-z)
$$

To obtain a cumulative distribution function $F_{XY}$, you would integrate over the probability density function $f_{XY}$. In such case, inevitably, you would observe that $F_{XY}(z, -z) = F_{XY}(-z, z)$. So multiple inputs could lead to the same outputs, so there is no [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) for it.

Comment: Another point worth signaling is that a multivariate cdf at a random value, $F_X(X)$, is no longer distributed as a Uniform $\mathcal U(0,1)$ variable.