# Drawing numbers using the CDF

Tags: random-generation, multinomial-logit

Say I have a (generally high-dimensional) random variable $X$ with known, continuous CDF $F(X)$.

Is there a good algorithm for drawing values of $X$ that doesn't require that I calculate the joint density?

I'm specifically interested in the GEV distribution used in the latent variable formulation of the nested logit:
$$F\left(\vec\nu\right) = \exp\left(- ∑_{n ∈ N} \left(∑_{k∈n} \exp\left(\frac{-\nu_k}{λ_n}\right)\right)^{λ_n}\right).$$
That distribution should have analytic PDFs, but they're pretty gross (and are going to get even grosser with multiple layers of nests).

[Edit: this question was labelled a duplicate of [Inverse of cumulative density function for Multivariate Normal Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530488/inverse-of-cumulative-density-function-for-multivariate-normal-distribution). It's not obvious why -- is the assumption that the inverse-transform algorithm is the **only** algorithm for drawing from a CDF? That doesn't seem right.]

Comment: I guess I could just use MCMC-MH, if I approximate the pdf $f(\vec\nu)$ with the probability of being in some small neighbourhood of $\vec\nu$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MCMC-MH algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) requires the ratio of the PDFs at the proposal value $x'$ and the existing value $x_t$. Let $K$ be the dimension of $X$.
We can approximate the ratio by looking at the ratio of probabilities that $X$ is in a neighbourhood of $x'$ or $x_t$
$$
\frac{f(x')}{f(x)} = \frac{\lim_{e \to 0}P[X \in x' \pm e]/e^K}{
\lim_{e \to 0}P[X \in x_t \pm e]/e^K}
 = \lim_{e \to 0}
\frac{P[X \in x' \pm e]}{
P[X \in x_t \pm e]}
\approx 
\frac{P[X \in x' \pm \epsilon]}{
P[X \in x_t \pm \epsilon]},
$$
where the approximation should hold for small $\epsilon$.

However it's not obvious how to use that approximation in log-space, which will likely be important given that both the numerator and the denominator will be very close to 0. In particular,
$$
\log P[X \in x' \pm \epsilon] = \log\left(P[X < x' + \epsilon]
- P[X < x' - \epsilon] \right) \\ \neq \log\left(P[X < x' + \epsilon]\right)
- \log \left(P[X < x' - \epsilon] \right).
$$

Comment: Since this is approximate, you cannot conclude at an exact simulation anyway. You should look for a latent structure such that $F$ appears like an integrated probability. For instance, the exponential of a sum equal to the product of exponentials hints at this probability being the probability of a maximum of rvs.